# Confusion regarding the right hand thumb rule

Tags: magnetics, magnetic-flux

I am confused regarding the use of the right hand thumb rule . There is two use cases for this rule :

1- The first when the thumb points in the direction of the current the fingers points in the direction of the magnetic field.

2- The second when the fingers point in the direction of the current the thumb will point in the direction of the filed.

I need to understand in which case we use the rule number 1 and in which case we use the rule number 2 ??

Comment: They're exactly equivalent, it just depends on whether you're considering the current as a line or as a loop.

Comment: Check this for both: https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/mcat/physical-processes/magnetism-mcat/a/using-the-right-hand-rule